# PhpStorm file watcher "Error: Cannot find module" with babel plugins in a rollupjs script (no executable available), plugins globally installed

Tags: phpstorm, file-watcher

I can't seem to be able to resolve this, hoping someone might be able to help.

I have configured a file watcher to check for changes in a source directory. When a change is found, it runs the following tool: -

**Program**: `C:\xampp\htdocs\currentproject\packages\node_modules\.bin\rollup`

**Arguments**: `-c C:\xampp\htdocs\currentproject\packages\source_directory\rollup.config.js`

It is finding the rollup script OK but then I run into an issue as the `rollup.config.js` file calls babel as a plugin: -

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel"

plugins: [
  babel({})
],
```

babel.config.js: -

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components"
  ],
}
```

It finds this config file OK but then I get the following error: -

```
(plugin babel) Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties' from 'C:\xampp\htdocs\currentproject'
```

Now I understand how to configure external tools in PhpStorm but **@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties** does not have a `.bin/executable`, only a .js file. I have also tried installing it globally via yarn and created a Windows environment variable to point to the global yarn directory but to no avail - I still get the same error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: do you have `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` installed next to rollup, in `\currentproject\packages\node_modules`? Also, what working directory did you set up for your file watcher?

Comment: That sorted the issue, thanks @lena